# Why does using wp_register_style without wp_enqueue load and print CSS tags in the front-end?

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

I have this piece of code that registers a CSS in a child theme and when visiting the front-end `my_css` is actually included. Why is that ? I thought that registering meant `registering for later use` to allow - among other things - conditional enqueuing of stylesheets/scripts. This shouldn't be working without enqueuing `my_css` at some point, right ?

```php
function register_my_styles()
{
    wp_register_style('parent_theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', null, 'all');
    wp_register_style('my_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/src/css/my_css', array('parent_theme'), null, 'all');
}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'register_my_styles');
```

Commenting out `wp_register_style('my_css` at least works :] but the way it behaves prevents me from using conditional enqueuing since `my_css` is rendered on the front-end by just using `wp_register_style`.

Now the funky part is: I am using ParentTheme 4.10.4 as a parent theme. When I downgrade for each version all the way to 4.0.1 then `wp_register_style` works normally and doesn't output the CSS line on the frond-end.

Which would be fine but enqueuing also doesn't work:

```php
function register_my_styles()
{
    wp_register_style('parent_theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', null, 'all');
    wp_register_style('my_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/src/css/my_css', array('parent_theme'), null, 'all');
}

function enqueue_my_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('parent_theme');
    wp_enqueue_style('my_css');
}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'register_my_styles');
add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'enqueue_my_styles');
```

What am I missing and misunderstanding here ?

## EDIT:

Fixing `add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'enqueue_my_styles');` with `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles');` fixed the problem for every version of ParentTheme < 4.10.x. and the rest of functions.php, with conditional enqueuing of styles now work as expected.

So I am inclined to believe there's a problem on the parent theme's side (Divi).

Things were apparently working in some specific conditions for a while despite `wp_enqueue_style` not working and that's why it escaped me for some time.

Comment: "This shouldn't be working without enqueuing my_css at some point, right ?" - yes, if there are no stylesheets on the page where their dependencies include the "my_css". And actually, there's no hook named "wp_enqueue_style" and instead, you should use `wp_enqueue_scripts` - for enqueuing JS and CSS files.

Comment: What is `ParentTheme`? Do you have a link? If you've narrowed it down to specific versions what changed in those versions? Did you ask `ParentTheme` support? 3rd party theme dev support is off-topic here. This abnormal behaviour is very likely caused by the parent theme based on what you've said in your question. Sally is right though, these are the incorrect hooks for enqueing scripts and styles

Comment: @TomJNowell: Parent Theme is Divi. Even though it's obviously doing something different from one version to another I think the problem is on my side. Haven't yet pinpointed the difference.

Comment: @SallyCJ: Thanks, I have to understand how the default work for wp_register_style. I changed `wp_enqueue_style` to `wp_enqueue_scripts` but it's not enough to solve the problem. What works is using a function that do both registering styles and enqueuing styles and put it in `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Comment: I downgraded the parent theme (Divi) to 4.9.x serie and the original code, with registering and enqueuing in different (and correct) hooks now work as intended. I'll asking for third party support now that I am confident the change was introduced in 4.10.x serie.